# Syntax highlighting html tags in doxygen comments in emacs

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, doxygen

I currently use doxymacs to syntax highlight doxygen comments and keywords in the C++ files on a collaborative project I'm working on.

However, in the project, there are "plans" files which are basically very long doxygen comments with lots of todos, bugs etc, all using html tags for organisation and presentation.

At present doxymacs only highlights keywords like "todo" and "bug" etc. How can I make it also syntax highlight the html tags within the doxygen comment?

I can do this by switching to "html-mode" but then I lose the standard doxymacs highlighting of "todo" etc. Just being able to use both modes together or combine them would be useful.

So for example, if I had:

```cpp
/*!
    \todo Test todo
    <ul>
     <li> Some text. </li>
     <li> Some more text. </li>
    </ul>

*/
```

I'd like the `<ul>` tags etc to be coloured a different colour to the normal text within the `/*! */` comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will font-lock anything in `<>` as keywords in comments in c-derived modes:

```
(defun my-c-font-lock-doxy-html (limit)
  (while (re-search-forward "<.+?>" limit 'move)
    (let ((beg (match-beginning 0))
          (end (match-end 0)))
      (if (nth 4 (syntax-ppss beg))
          (when (nth 4 (syntax-ppss end))
            (c-put-font-lock-face beg end 'font-lock-keyword-face))
        (goto-char end))))
  nil)

(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil '((my-c-font-lock-doxy-html))))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
```

Comment: Does this just highlight HTML comments like C/C++ comments? If so, that's not what I'm looking for. I want HTML code which appears in C++ comments to be highlighted as HTML rather than with comment colours.

Comment: It won't do full-blown HTML highlighting, but any `<whatever>` type tags will be highlighted as keywords (only in comments).  Try it :)

Comment: Fantastic! Works perfectly! Also gives me a nice bit of code to examine and look further into emacs font-modes :)! Thanks! I'll award the bounty as soon as I'm allowed :)

Comment: Glad it works for you.  BTW, I wouldn't use what I did here as an example of how you normally add highlighting.  I had to go about things in an unusual way to ensure it would only happen inside comments.